# How can I snapshot and restore firecracker vm running containers using firecracker-containerd?

Tags: containerd, firecracker

I am running containers in Firecracker micro-VM using firecracker contained. I was able to create a firecracker VM and run a container inside it. However, I haven't found any APIs in firecracker-containerd to snapshot and restore a VM running container that I can directly use in my GO code. Are there any APIs there for that? I have seen APIs for snapshotting and restoring VMs in FIrecracker-microvm/firecracker repo where it sends requests to the API server for pausing/snapshotting/resuming/ restoring VMs.

https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker/blob/main/docs/snapshotting/snapshot-support.md

Is it the way to follow for snapshotting a firecracker VM running containers?